# Error creating bean 'entityManagerFactory', Nested HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Many question have been asked on this topic, but none them seems to resolve my issue.
I trying a sample project with Maven, Spring, Hibernate and JPA with Mysql 5.5. It is a test desktop app. I don't know, where I am gong wrong. mvn clean install is giving Build Success. But when I run I am getting following exception. Help required. See the Code below.

```
> ************** BEGINNING PROGRAM **************
Feb 20, 2015 6:36:44 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@758fc9: startup date [Fri Feb 20 18:36:44 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Feb 20, 2015 6:36:45 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [app-config.xml]
Feb 20, 2015 6:36:45 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider registerDefaultFilters
INFO: JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
Feb 20, 2015 6:36:45 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider registerDefaultFilters
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
Feb 20, 2015 6:36:45 PM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from class path resource [database.properties]
Feb 20, 2015 6:36:45 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor <init>
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
Feb 20, 2015 6:36:45 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@e91f5d: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,stockDao,stockService,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,dataSource,entityManagerFactory,jpaDialect]; root of factory hierarchy
Feb 20, 2015 6:36:46 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Feb 20, 2015 6:36:46 PM org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.PersistenceUnitReader determinePersistenceUnitRootUrl
INFO: apppersistence.xml should be located inside META-INF directory; cannot determine persistence unit root URL for class path resource [apppersistence.xml]
Feb 20, 2015 6:36:46 PM org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean createNativeEntityManagerFactory
INFO: Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'modalUnit'
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version - Hibernate Annotations 3.5.2-Final
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.5.2-Final
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
[main] INFO org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
[main] INFO org.hibernate.ejb.Version - Hibernate EntityManager 3.5.2-Final
[main] INFO org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration - Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: modalUnit
    ...]
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.prac.core.modal.Stock
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.prac.core.modal.Stock on table Stock
[main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration - Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
Feb 20, 2015 6:36:47 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@e91f5d: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,stockDao,stockService,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,dataSource,entityManagerFactory,jpaDialect]; root of factory hierarchy
*********************** ERROR ****************************
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stockDao': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [app-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1073)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.prac.core.App.main(App.java:21)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [app-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:529)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:495)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:629)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:338)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.applyBeanValidationConstraintsOnDDL(AnnotationConfiguration.java:477)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.applyConstraintsToDDL(AnnotationConfiguration.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:403)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1206)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1453)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1081)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:677)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:95)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/geronimo/osgi/locator/ProviderLocator
    at javax.validation.Validation$DefaultValidationProviderResolver.getValidationProviders(Validation.java:209)
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:173)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:82)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.geronimo.osgi.locator.ProviderLocator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 49 more
```

My Code is Following
**Modal**

```
package com.prac.core.modal;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Stock")
public class Stock {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "Stock_Id")
    private Integer stockId;

    @Column(name = "Stock_Code")
    private String stockCode;

    @Column(name = "Stock_Name")
    private String stockName;

    public Integer getStockId() {
        return stockId;
    }

    public void setStockId(Integer stockId) {
        this.stockId = stockId;
    }

    public String getStockCode() {
        return stockCode;
    }

    public void setStockCode(String stockCode) {
        this.stockCode = stockCode;
    }

    public String getStockName() {
        return stockName;
    }

    public void setStockName(String stockName) {
        this.stockName = stockName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Stock [StockId =" + stockId + ", stockCode =" + stockCode + ", stockName =" + stockName + "]";
    }
}
```

**Dao**

```
package com.prac.core.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.prac.core.modal.Stock;

@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class StockDao {

        @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager entityManager;

        public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
            return entityManager;
        }

        public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
            this.entityManager = entityManager;
        }

        public void insert(Stock stock) {
            entityManager.persist(stock);
        }

        public List<Stock> getAllList() {
            Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT S FROM Stock S");
            List<Stock> sto = (List<Stock>)query.getResultList();
            return sto;
        }
}
```

**Service**

```
package com.prac.core;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.prac.core.dao.StockDao;
import com.prac.core.modal.Stock;

@Component
public class StockService {

    @Autowired
    private StockDao stockDao;

    public void addStock(Stock stock) {
        stockDao.insert(stock);
    }

    public List<Stock> getAllStock() {
        return stockDao.getAllList();
    }
}
```

**database.proporties**

> jpa.jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>   jpa.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prac 
>   jpa.jdbc.username=root
>   jpa.jdbc.password=*******

**apppersistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="modalUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.prac.core.modal.Stock</class>
        <properties> 
            <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="none" />
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners" value="false"/> -->
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jpa.jdbc.driverClassName}" />
            <property name="url" value="${jpa.jdbc.url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${jpa.jdbc.username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${jpa.jdbc.password}" />
           <!--  NONE
            </property>   -->
        </properties>  
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**app-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- enabling annotation driven configuration / -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.prac" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        p:entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Enable the transaction annotations, by this declarative transactions 
        can be used -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <!-- ==================== Data source definitions ==================== -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jpa.jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jpa.jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jpa.jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jpa.jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>
    <!-- ==================== Hibernate Entity Manager ==================== -->

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:/apppersistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="modalUnit" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
                <!-- <property name="validation.mode" value="NONE" />  -->
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
</beans>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.prac.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringHibJPAEx</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringHibJPAEx</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <!-- <spring.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version> -->
    <spring.version>3.0.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hib.version>3.5.2-Final</hib.version>
    <hibjpa.version>1.0.1.Final</hibjpa.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>        
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.34</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hib.version}</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${hib.version}</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>     
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.19.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0-6</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.10</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.10</version>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
         <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>     
</project>
```

**MainMethod Class - App**

```
package com.prac.core;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.prac.core.modal.Stock;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try {
            //System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
            System.out.println("************** BEGINNING PROGRAM **************");
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("app-config.xml");
            StockService stockService = (StockService) context.getBean("stockService");

            Stock stock = new Stock();
            stock.setStockCode("A1");
            stock.setStockName("Amar");

            stockService.addStock(stock);
            System.out.println("Stock : " + stock + " added successfully");

            List<Stock> stockList = stockService.getAllStock();
            System.out.println("The list of all Stock = " + stockList);

            System.out.println("************** ENDING PROGRAM *****************");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("*********************** ERROR ****************************");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try to rename apppersistence.xml to persistence.xml? And  Path must be like src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

Comment: @SemihEker, I tried your suggestion. Same Error.

Comment: Are you running osgi? Which app-server? The missing class is in geronimo-osgi-locator, but i wonder why you would need it.

Comment: @MartinBaumgartner, Its an normal test app, without any app server. With java main method.

Comment: Can you put it on github or somewhere else? Hard to analyse without a debugger

Comment: Otherwise, open BeanValidationActivator and set a breakpoint on line 92 and try to step through it.

Comment: @MartinBaumgartner Here is the [github URL](https://github.com/shethaa/SpringHibJPAEx)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71337/discussion-between-amar-and-martin-baumgartner).

Comment: @MartinBaumgartner. I am relatively new in JPA, Hibernate and springs. How do you open BeanValidationActivator? Also I don't required Validator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the geronimo-osgi-locator to add the missing class file. It seems tomcat and other app-servers also ship those class packaged with their appserver.

The javax.validation.Validation.java in line 209 accesses the ProviderLocator, which is imported in line 38.

```
javax.validation.Validation.java
```

`import org.apache.geronimo.osgi.locator.ProviderLocator;
                    List serviceProviders = ProviderLocator.getServices(ValidationProvider.class.getName(), this.getClass(), cl);`

Maven Dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-osgi-locator</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanx @MartinBaumgartner, Can explain me the issue.

Comment: Added in my answer above.

Comment: I just want to warn anyone coming from Google that if you get this error in a unit test, where you don't have a server or a JAX-RS Application, this is probably not the only thing you're missing. So finding it may not help.