# configuration error when using jpa and spring

Tags: jpa

I am getting the following error when i run my application in eclipse Helios by creating a dynamic web project. I have also used cxf to autogenerate classes from wsdl.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml]
```

My persistence.xml is in META-INF in the src folder:
Please help solve the error.
I have used JPA with spring to retrieve from data base.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a mechanism in your application to load your spring contexts. As you are talking about a webapplication, i guess your context gets loaded in the web.xml. 
In your web.xml there will be a section like:

```
<context-param> 
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
  <param-value>/META-INF/*.xml</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

This pattern also matches your persistence.xml.

So lets change this to:

```
 <param-value>/WEB-INF/springContext*.xml</param-value>
```

Now, spring will only load context-files starting with springContext and end with xml.

Unluckily, your question doesn't explain your app in detail, so this is a wild guess.

Comment: <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

Comment: that is my web.xml file. i have a persistence.xml and a spring.xml

Comment: <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
 <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
 <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />

<import resource="classpath:/META-INF/persistence.xml" />

Comment: i have written the above statement to import the persistence file in beans.xml. but still throws the error

Comment: Remove import persistence.xml and add your complete spring.xml to your question.

Comment: im not able to add links since im new. if i remove the import how will i link the persistence.xml and beans.xml??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630185/error-creating-bean-entitymanagerfactory-nested-hibernateexception-unable-to/  and https://github.com/shethaa/SpringHibJPAEx